# SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with advanced services installation does not have all options

Tags: installation, sql-server-2008r2-express, management-studio-express

I don't know how else to ask this, and I think the title could be changed. I've been downloading different SQL Server Express versions, and I can't seem to find the one that has the Management Studio Express, the fulltext search, and the Reporting Services, replication, bi dev studio, management tools basic, sql client connectivity sdk, ms sync framework. I have found some installations have some of these, but not all of these features. To be honest I would like the full text search, the management studio express, and the bi dev studio, but they are lacking. where can I get these? Any help. I found info here:

```
 http://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/2024/introduction-to-sql-server-express-2008-r2/
 http://www.sqlmag.com/article/sql-server/sql-server-2008-r2-express-installation-options
```

I've downloaded and tried:

- SQLEXPR32_x86_ENU
- SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU
- SQLManagementStudio_x86_ENU
- SQLEXPRWT_x86_ENU

I installed the bare bones SQL Server 2008 R2 Express and I notice if I go to add shared features it doesn't show some of the other features, but if I add a new instance it gives me some (but not the ones I need). Can someone guide me please? Do I need to uninstall everything and try again?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My solution was to uninstall the sql express that I originally installed and then reinstall with advanced services and that included everything. I have no idea why it was not letting add anything additionally. Maybe someone has some thoughts on that (or some facts). Anyways it installed completely now. Thank you Dan for your efforts. Greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

What you're looking for is probably SQL Server 2008 R2 Express with Advanced Services. It's not SQLEXPRADV_x86_ENU which was mentioned in your post - that one looks not R2 version.

Comment: hey thanks for your answer. I forgot to mark my answer as the correct answer. If you look. I had solved it actually. Again thanks for posting something, otherwise I wouldn't have marked the answer. I'm sure someone will find that useful if they do the same thing that I did....that is install the wrong version and try to add the rest of the funcionality.

Answer (score 1):

It's always difficult to find anything on Microsoft's site:

http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=22985

Thats the Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 RTM - Management Studio Express

Comment: I found this one, but it does not have the bi dev studio or the full text search. is that in another download? this is a pain.

Comment: Go here: http://www.microsoft.com/betaexperience/pd/SQLEXP08V2/enus/, then select SQL database w/tools

Comment: I have that one too. Maybe I should have posted the links of where I got those files. I don't know what it is. If I could just get the full text search I could live without the bi dev studio for now, but neither one of these had it.

Answer (score 0):

The most actual link:

Microsoft® SQL Server® 2008 R2 SP2 - Express Edition

http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/confirmation.aspx?id=30438

**Basic setup:**

SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe - SQL Express 2008 R2 SP

**Include SSMS:**

SQLEXPRWT_x64_ENU.exe

**Include Reporting Services:**

SQLEXPRADV_x64_ENU.exe - SQL Express 2008 R2 SP with Advanced Services

**Separate SSMS install:**

SQLManagementStudio_x64_ENU.exe